# Operations with surds

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $a=3\sqrt2,$ simplify $(2a)^3$

(Original screenshots: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWELh.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysqWT.png))

I have tried this even on my calculator and got it wrong, please show me the correct methodology.

I  did $(2)^3 + (3\sqrt2)^3$ and got wrong answer

Then: $(3\sqrt2)^3 \cdot (2)^3$

and got wrong asnwer too, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your steps, otherwise you won't learn anything as this is pretty straightforward, I'm afraid.

Comment: Done. That is the only way I can think of doing this.

Comment: So you're using the 'rule' $(xy)^3=x^3+y^3$, is that it?

Comment: Use instead $(a\cdot b)^2 = a^n\cdot b^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have made two errors.  The main one is that the formula $2a$ does not mean $2+a$.  It means 2 multiplied by $a$, that is $2\cdot a$.  To compute this on a calculator, you need to take $a$, which is $3\sqrt2$—that is, $3$ multiplied by $\sqrt 2$—and multiply that by $2$.  The result, $2a$, will be around 8.4.

Then you cube $2a$, which means you calculate $(2a)\times(2a)\times(2a)$.  The result should be around 600 or so.

---

To compute this symbolically, you start by substituting $a$ with its definition: $(2a)^3$ becomes $$(2\cdot 3\cdot\sqrt2)^3.$$

We can combine the 2 and 3 right away, because we know $2\cdot 3 = 6$: $$(6\cdot\sqrt 2)^3.$$

There is a rule that says that $(p\cdot q)^r = p^r\cdot q^r$. Here we have $p=6, q=\sqrt 2,$ and $r=3$:

$$6^3 \cdot (\sqrt 2)^3$$

Then $6^3 = 216$ and $(\sqrt2)^3 = \sqrt2\cdot\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt2 = 2\cdot \sqrt 2$, so we get:

$$216\cdot 2\cdot\sqrt 2 = 432\cdot \sqrt 2$$

This is as simple as we can make the answer.

---

The other error you made is not important, in light of the first one, but it may trip you up later, so I mention it anyway.  If you did need to compute $(2 + a)^3$, you *cannot* compute the right answer by computing $2^3$ and $a^3$ separately and adding the results.  $(2+a)^3$ means that you do the addition before the cube, not the other way around, and in this case the order makes a difference, as your calculator will confirm.

It is easy to confuse this with the situation where you need to compute $(2\cdot a)^3$. There, it *does* work to cube $2$ and $a$ separately and multiply the results; you get the same answer as if you had multiplied $2$ and $a$ first and cubed the result.